# Extract multiple {fieldName} from a string to create a values hashmap

Tags: typescript

I get a simple situation in typescript.

I have a model with some strings inside of it.

For example

```
let message = 'Updated user {userName}. Set new name {newName} instead of old {oldName}.'
```

Currently the actual values of these fields are stores in a `this.fields` attribute.

We were doing inline replacement to return a "filled" message text. Using something like:

```
replaceFields(message): string {
    return Object.keys(this.fields).reduce((currentMessage, field) => {
        let values: String[] = this.fields[field];
        if (values) {
            return currentMessage.replace(`{${field}}`, values.join(', '));
        } else {
            return currentMessage;
        }
    }, message);
}
```

For translation needs we need to do things in another way.

We would like not to replace inline but instead return somethink like:

```
message = {
    text: 'Updated user {userName}. Set new name {newName} instead of old {oldName}.',
    values: {
        userName: 'actual_username',
        newName: 'bob',
        oldName: 'jack'
    }
}
```

So we can use angular ngx-translate third party which will then use in a pipe:

`My message: {{message.text |translate:values}}`

I'm quite new in Typescript and I don't know how to exctract fieldNames from the string and then simply add them in the kind of `values` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a regex to get all the values from the message string and then use them to create an object. The following example will use a regex to find all strings within curly braces and then search the fields object for them:

```
class Message {
    constructor(public text: string, public values: any) { };
}

function GetMessage(text: string, fields: any): Message {
    let values: any = {};

    let regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/{(.*?)}/g);
    let match: RegExpExecArray;

    while (match = regex.exec(text)) {
        let field = match[1];
        values[field] = fields[field] ? fields[field].join(', ') : '';
    }

    return new Message(text, values)
}

let fields: any = { userName: ['theUser'], newName: ['theNew'], oldName: ['theOld'] };
let str = 'Updated user {userName}. Set new name {newName} instead of old {oldName}.';

let msg = GetMessage(str, fields);
console.log(msg);
```

The console logs this output:

```
msg : Object {
    text : "Updated user {userName}. Set new name {newName} instead of old {oldName}."
    values : Object { 
        userName: "theUser", 
        newName: "theNew", 
        oldName: "theOld" 
    }
}
```